# Rate limiting for services deployed in AKS

Tags: azure, spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have one service which serves as an endpoint to upload documents into our system. We started doing some load tests and notices that we get some connection timeout errors for some of our files.

In my project we use:

1. Java 9
2. Spring Boot 2.0
3. Azure AKS
4. By default, we have ingress controllers in front of our services

Together with my teammates, we tried to collect some statistics and that is what we have:

1. If we upload 2000 documents with 5MB per one document in 128 threads we have the following errors: Error Status 999:194, Error Status 504:1
2. If we upload 2000 documents with 250KB per one document in 48 threads sometimes we have the following errors: Error Status 999:2

I have checked AKS, Ingress, and Spring Boot documentation and I do not see that it has any rate limits enabled by default. Moreover, I do not see any errors in the logs of my Java App, so it seems that everything happens somewhere in AKS and Ingress.

You can find our ingress config example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ZZZ-ingress-dev-files-storage
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: files-storage
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "whitelisted-ips"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 151m
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - files-storage.dev.ZZZ-env.net
    secretName: tls-files-storage.dev.ZZZ-env.net

  rules:
  - host: files-storage.dev.ZZZ-env.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: files-storage-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

And here you can find examples of logs from ingress controller:

```
14:30:28  2019/08/05 06:28:20 [warn] 43#43: *1177362 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /tmp/client-body/0000082261, client: 91.185.25.194, server: file-storage.test.ZZZ-env.net, request: "POST /ZZZ/files HTTP/1.1", host: "file-storage.test.ZZZ-env.net"
14:30:28  2019/08/05 06:28:20 [warn] 43#43: *1177342 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /tmp/client-body/0000082262, client: 91.185.25.194, server: file-storage.test.ZZZ-env.net, request: "POST /ZZZ/files HTTP/1.1", host: "file-storage.test.ZZZ-env.net"
```

Do you have any ideas what can be a reason of "rejected" request? Something in AKS or Ingress configs enabled by default?

Comment: How do you create the ingress and what is the configuration for the ingress? Can you show the YAML file for the ingress?

Comment: what do ingress logs show?

Comment: @CharlesXu I've added YAML that shows ingress configs

Comment: Take a look at the [`annotations:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#custom-max-body-size). I think it's the possible reason.

Comment: @CharlesXu According to the documentation, this config is for one request, where we do not exceed the limit. The biggest file that we upload is 5MB and proxy-body-size is 151MB

Comment: How do you install the ingress?

Comment: It's a part of our helm-charts provisioning

Comment: How do you set the resource request and limit of the ingress container?

Comment: We do not set it explicitly anywhere, so I guess that we have default values - https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml#L429-L435

Comment: @CharlesXu we haven't reached any limits so far, so I do not think that it is a problem

Comment: I've also added a few lines from logs, I do not see any other errors or warnings